# Cucumber installation for clojure outdated

Tags: clojure, installation, cucumber

I am currently following this: [Cucumber tutorial](https://github.com/mjul/cucumber-tutorial), however it seems that it is out of date. Does anyone know of a newly updated tutorial? Or how to set up cucumber in a Clojure project?

Comment: Here is the updated tutorial for cucumber in clojure:

https://github.com/punkisdead/lein-cucumber

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated tutorial for cucumber in clojure:

github.com/punkisdead/lein-cucumber